# Update Query matching a Monthly date

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table tblQA that stores employee quality assessment data. It has 14 yes/no fields that track various trends. (see code below) I know that storing calculations is normally a no-no but the query as it stands runs for 2-3 minutes and I only have 1/3 of the expected data for the year. What I would like to do is run a query once myself monthly and store that data in a table so that it can quickly be accessed by the many supervisors that look at it. I want the average of the 14 trends for a given month to be stored in a table that has those 14 trends and the date in "mmmm yyyy" format. I want finalized QA's for a given month and the average error rate for each trending item. I tried this query:

```
UPDATE DISTINCTROW tblQA, tblAverageTrends 
    SET tblAverageTrends.Appeal = Avg([tblQA].[Appeal]),
        tblAverageTrends.NRP = Avg([tblQA].[NRP]),
        tblAverageTrends.ChurnEscalation = Avg([tblQA].[ChurnEscalation]),
        tblAverageTrends.ProtocolNotFollowed = Avg([tblQA].[ProtocolNotFollowed]), 
        tblAverageTrends.Resubmission = Avg([tblQA].[Resubmission]),
        tblAverageTrends.Transfer = Avg([tblQA].[Transfer]),
        tblAverageTrends.ChargeCorrection = Avg([tblQA].[ChargeCorrection]),
        tblAverageTrends.Distribution = Avg([tblQA].[Distribution]),
        tblAverageTrends.Adjustment = Avg([tblQA].[Adjustment]),
        tblAverageTrends.PayorUpdate = Avg([tblQA].[PayorUpdate]),
        tblAverageTrends.TOBPOS = Avg([tblQA].[TOBPOS]),
        tblAverageTrends.CaseBilledUntimely = Avg([tblQA].[CaseBilledUntimely]),
        tblAverageTrends.Noting = Avg([tblQA].[Noting]),
        tblAverageTrends.MovedChargesIncorrectly = Avg([tblQA].[MovedChargesIncorrectly]) 
        WHERE (((tblQA.Final)=True) 
            AND ((Format$([tblQA].[NoteDate],'mmmm yyyy'))="September 2017"));
```

And I preseeded tblAverage Trends with the Date September 2017. Nothing updates however. I'm a scrub at SQL (I'm trying to learn) but I set this up with the query designer in Access. [Access Query Designer View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxquw.jpg) I feel like what my statement is missing is linking avg's to the correct row that specifies the September QA's but I cant figure out how to make the Access query designer do that.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
[tblQA].[NoteDate] Between DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) - 1, 1) And DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 0)
```

That will use an index on NoteDate. If this is not present, add it.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not knowedgeable about this. Add it as a new line in the SQL? or as an expression in the Query Designer? Or Something else?

Comment: No. It's the table.